# unix timestamp doesn't work in amcharts for showing chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using a unix timestamp as a category field of my chart but it doesn't work. Here is a sample of my json data:

```
{
    "id": 1546387200,
    "upload_id": 1,
    "bg": 23
}
```

The id is a unix timestamp and I'm using this field as a category field of my chart:

```
"categoryField": "id",
"categoryAxis": {
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "labelsEnabled": true,
    "tickLength": 0
},
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Can you please share your complete chart config or create a code pen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thomasdesaranno-r0629748/pen/VRvyVa

Comment: btw if you can answer another question as wel. In the chart i shared with codepen i want to import a second json file, and make a second chart with its values. How do i do that?

Comment: Please create another question for that issue.

Comment: i already did, can you take a look at it? here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884920/multiple-datasets-with-dataloader-amcharts-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend switching to amcharts4, because it is much more flexible and has even new chart types. You can migrate easily, beginning with just one chart. You can use amcharts3 and amcharts4 in parallel ([Migration Guide](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/)).

To solve your problem you should set the `parseDates` property for your categoryAxis and set it to `true` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryaxis/#parseDates_property)).

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "labelsEnabled": true,
    "tickLength": 0,
    "parseDates": true
},
```

I created [this code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZVQwb) as reference. Hope that helps.